# Sql server select - varchar containing column name and value

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to add a bunch of c# code to test values against a table. Connecting directly to the data source is out of the question (this needs to be static code).

The output is

```
X.AddColumn("ColumnName",ColumnValue);
```

I would like to get a SQL statement that, for a table returns the above pattern, listing each column of a row, iterating through every row in the table.

I was hoping for a select statement in the db that I could copy and paste result set of, ideally one that went through columns dynamically to save me doing something like below for each table I wish to output.

```
SELECT 'X.AddColumn("ColumnName1", ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnName1, 100) +');' AS Col1
...
'X.AddColumn("ColumnNameN", ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, ColumnNameN, 100) +');' AS ColN
FROM
Schema.Table1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the top of my head, this is a 2 step process:

Run the statement below. It will create a query for each of the columns of your table (something like `select 'x.AddColumn("Column1", ' + Convert(varchar, Column1, 100) +' )' from dbo.Table1`)

```
SELECT 'select ''x.AddColumn("' + c.column_name 
       + '", ''+ Convert(varchar, ' + c.column_name 
       + ',100)+'' )'' from ' + c.table_schema + '.' 
       + c.table_name 
FROM   information_schema.columns c 
WHERE  c.table_name = 'Table1' 
       AND c.table_schema = 'dbo'
```

Copy the output of the statement above and run it. It should give you the desired output.

Comment: Thanks for that, I thought the answer might be as such. I was just hoping there might have been a one step query, although I suppose I could select this answer into a `VARCHAR(MAX)` and execute using dynamic sql.